# Using Regex to detect if string exists

Tags: php, regex

I need to use PHP's `preg_match()` and Regex to detect the following conditions:

*If a URL path is one of the following:*

- `products/new items`
- `new items/products`
- `new items/products/brand name`

*Do something...*

I can't seem to figure out how to check if the a string exists before or after the word products. The closest I can get is:

```
if (preg_match("([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)\/products\/([a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)", $url_path)) {
  // Do something
```

Would anyone know a way to check if the first part of the string exists within the one regex line?

Comment: You looking for something like [`this`](https://regex101.com/r/TFHR36/1/)  ?

Comment: You can use alternation `([\w_ ]+)\/products|products\/([\w_ ]+)`

Comment: Or [`'~([^\/]*)(?:^|\/)products(?:\/|$)([^\/]*)~'`](https://regex101.com/r/TFHR36/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but that will match `products` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an alternation with an optional group for the last item making the `/` part of the optional group.

If you are only looking for a match, you can omit the capturing groups.

```
(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+/products(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)?|products/[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non catpuring group

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+/products` Match 1+ times what is listed in the character class, `/` followed by products
  - `(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+)?` Optionally match `/` and what is listed in the character class
  - `|` Or
  - `products/[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+` Match `products/`, match 1+ times what is listed
- `)` Close group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wQPx2N/1)

Note that `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+` might be shortened to `[\w ]+`

Comment: This is odd, when I implement it with words other than "product" (as my site requires) it only detects the first instance, eg https://regex101.com/r/0KfEjo/1

Comment: @MeltingDog You have to enable the global flag `g` at the right top on regex101 https://regex101.com/r/0KfEjo/2

Comment: @MeltingDog But surely do not use any `g` modifier in PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alternation

```
([\w ]+)\/products|products\/([\w ]+)
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/TFHR36/3/)

Note:- I am not sure how you're using the matched values, if you don't need back reference to any specific values then you can avoid capturing group, i.e.

```
 [\w ]+\/products|products\/[\w ]+
```